# Android Asset folder image automatically copying to gallary

Tags: android, hybrid-mobile-app

Greetings dear readers,

I have this query which the team is facing. We are developing a hybrid app for android platform and ran into one issue that seems to get complicated.

Here it goes.

Team is calling static HTML pages(no control on html content modification) in a web view, the html page content involves images which are taken from asset folder. Now when we are debugging the application on android device, asset folder images are getting copied automatically in gallery.

I am not a native coder but it seems asset folder images will be copied automatically. Please correct me if I am wrong. Is there any way, When I debug my app on device I could restrict this automatically copying of asset images to device gallery.

As I am not from Android, this might be the silly question but any help in this scenario would be highly appreciated.

I have researched on google to find out possible fix but unable to find one.

Guys, please suggest.....Any leads on this....

[image]

Comment: show your folder structure. if you have done everything as you should assets folder's images will not be accessible to device gallery or any other apps.

Comment: updated the folders sturucture @IllegalArgument

Comment: Well i cannot believe that files fom assets are displayed by the gallery apps. The gallery app simple has no access to assets directories of app. You say `copied to galery` But one can not copy 'to gallery` to begin with as it is no storage place. The gallery is an app which can display pictures who recide in your devices memory/sdcard. So if gallery displays someting the files are in external memory/sdcard. So find out first who copied files from assets to 'sdcard'. Find out the full absolute path to begin with.

Comment: From Thomas Gobolabs (not enough rep to comment) : it is the same behavior when you place images in "drawable" folders ?

Comment: @greenapps yes it's getting copied to external SD card

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want your photos being accessible from gallery, add .nomedia file to the folder copied onto the device. This will prevent photos from appearing into gallery.

Comment: can u please tell me where i have to add this file.

Comment: Sadly this most times will not work. Ive seen so many devices where such a file had no effect. You could give it a try though.

Comment: Your files are getting copied to external sd card. Find out the path of the directory & code which does it. Then after copying all images create the .nomedia file in the same directory as of images.